# How can I find Kubernetes memory default for a cron job?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes cron job that gets an OOMKilled (Out of Memory) message when running. This specific cron job runs once a day. The node itself has 4 GB of RAM.

Found somewhere that said the default for a cron job is 100 MB? Where can I view or change the default for Kubernetes cron jobs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just add resources and limits to that job so you can prevent it from being OOM killed. One thing to note is how resources and limits work. I have explained some scenarios in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54184886/what-is-the-use-case-of-setting-memory-request-less-than-limit-in-k8s/54203128#54203128) on Stack. It is worthy to check the official [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/#resource-requests-and-limits-of-pod-and-container) to avoid common mistakes and also CPU and Memory resources/limits work a little bit different.

About the default values of resources and limits it depends on where is your cluster. For example in my kubeadm I do not have any resources or limits by default in `default` namespace:

```
kubectl describe ns default
Name:         default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Active

No resource quota.

No resource limits.
```

And this is for GKE:

[image: GKE]

So your choice is to set up Requests and Limits for your namespace or just add it into the Job spec, like in this example:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: testing-hello
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: hi-there
            image: busybox
            args:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - date; echo "Hello, World!"
            resources:
              requests:
                cpu: "100Mi"
              limits:
                cpu: "100Mi"
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Also usually you would just set resources and limits per namespace as it is described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/manage-resources/memory-default-namespace/#create-a-namespace).